# error when running ruby server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to ruby on rails. Project was working fine I saved and closed the box. when I reopened it and tried running the server I got this:

```
/home/action/croquet/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `rRails' for main:Object (NameError)                                                           
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'                                                                         
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'                                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency' 
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'                                                                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                             
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'                                                                                              
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                  
        from /home/action/croquet/bin/spring:16:in `require'                                                                                                                                     
        from /home/action/croquet/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                            
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'                                                                                                                                                               
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `routes.rb:1:in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method 'rRails' for main:Object (NameError)                                                           ` ... hmm might be relevant? :)

Comment: i just did. seems like nothings wrong with it from my newbie eyes

Comment: Lower case r  in front of Rails.  But normally  add your stuff by editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typing mistake. It should be `Rails` not `rRails`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ȿµŁƮɦąɲąŁŁąµȡƹƹɲ, it might not be very long, and does just repeat a previous answer, but it DOES provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on `rRails`. It should be `Rails.applications.routes.draw`